# mySQL: Variable LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I'm using a SQL-statement to retrieve the top 5 entries in a list:

```
SELECT ... FROM table ORDER BY someColumn DESC LIMIT 5
```

The result will look something like this:

```
Name       Count
Person B   10
Person D   8
Person A   5
Person E   5
Person C   4
```

If there are more results with a value like the fifth entry in the list (4 in the example), I would like to show them too. Is there a way to achieve this with a single query?

So let's say the complete lists looks like this:

```
Name       Count
Person B   10
Person D   8
Person A   5
Person E   5
Person C   4
Person H   4
Person I   4
------------
Person G   3
Person F   1
Person J   1
```

How can I modify my query to return the first seven results? Obviosuly I can't use `LIMIT 7` or `WHERE Count >= 4`, as I don't know that in advance.

Comment: how come you can't use LIMIT 7? Use LIMIT 100

Comment: What happens when your data is `10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1`? Will you show the 7 rows with count = 10? Or 7 rows with count = 10 + 4 rows with count between 5 and 2?

Comment: @Salman: The description is clear. It will show the seven `10` s. Notice the two `5, 5` in the question.

Comment: @yper: In that case you get +1 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean you want the fist five results but also all other results which are **tied** in 5th place, right? One solution is to get the 5th result first - using a subquery - and then get what you need:

```
SELECT ...
FROM table
WHERE someColumn >=
    ( SELECT someColumn 
      FROM table 
      ORDER BY someColumn DESC 
      LIMIT 4, 1                      <-- only the 5th 
    )
ORDER BY someColumn DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

Sol 1: Use `LIMIT 100` or so, and eliminate unwanted rows in your program.

Sol 2: Execute two queries, most probaby that will be more costly:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... FROM table ORDER BY
  someColumn DESC LIMIT 5) 
  UNION (SELECT ... FROM table ORDER BY
         someColumn DESC LIMIT 50, 5);
```